# Hide content until its parent is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I hide each `p.list-group-item-text` in the following HTML, until its parent `a.list-group-item` is clicked, then hide again when anything else is clicked?

The solution must be compatible with mobile.

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading <b class="caret"></b></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum nisl ac elit commodo fringilla. Suspendisse varius nunc mauris, vitae egestas nunc cursus vitae. Ut congue odio libero, sit amet sodales arcu convallis ac. Nunc quis blandit
      metus. Aliquam hendrerit lectus vitae sapien placerat volutpat. Aenean nibh felis, volutpat sit amet maximus eget, consequat at orci. Integer pellentesque molestie elit. Donec placerat semper lacus vel blandit. Donec et dictum felis. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus consectetur diam a sagittis vestibulum. Fusce vestibulum sollicitudin venenatis.</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading <b class="caret"></b></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum nisl ac elit commodo fringilla. Suspendisse varius nunc mauris, vitae egestas nunc cursus vitae. Ut congue odio libero, sit amet sodales arcu convallis ac. Nunc quis blandit
      metus. Aliquam hendrerit lectus vitae sapien placerat volutpat. Aenean nibh felis, volutpat sit amet maximus eget, consequat at orci. Integer pellentesque molestie elit. Donec placerat semper lacus vel blandit. Donec et dictum felis. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus consectetur diam a sagittis vestibulum. Fusce vestibulum sollicitudin venenatis.</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/hfuswu6y/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the CSS `:focus` pseudo class selector. Just set `display: none` on the elements you want to hide, then set `display: block` on the same element when it's parent has focus.

```css
p.list-group-item-text {
    display: none;
}
a.list-group-item:focus p.list-group-item-text {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading <b class="caret"></b></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum nisl ac elit commodo fringilla. Suspendisse varius nunc mauris, vitae egestas nunc cursus vitae. Ut congue odio libero, sit amet sodales arcu convallis ac. Nunc quis blandit
      metus. Aliquam hendrerit lectus vitae sapien placerat volutpat. Aenean nibh felis, volutpat sit amet maximus eget, consequat at orci. Integer pellentesque molestie elit. Donec placerat semper lacus vel blandit. Donec et dictum felis. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus consectetur diam a sagittis vestibulum. Fusce vestibulum sollicitudin venenatis.</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading <b class="caret"></b></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum nisl ac elit commodo fringilla. Suspendisse varius nunc mauris, vitae egestas nunc cursus vitae. Ut congue odio libero, sit amet sodales arcu convallis ac. Nunc quis blandit
      metus. Aliquam hendrerit lectus vitae sapien placerat volutpat. Aenean nibh felis, volutpat sit amet maximus eget, consequat at orci. Integer pellentesque molestie elit. Donec placerat semper lacus vel blandit. Donec et dictum felis. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus consectetur diam a sagittis vestibulum. Fusce vestibulum sollicitudin venenatis.</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution! Im using this now and it works exactly as wanted!

Comment: @TinyGiant I am not trying to prove you wrong or any thing but chiel you mentioned you want content to hide even if heading is clicked again, **It needs to hide again when I click somewhere else. Even when I click on the list item header itself again! Thanks ** , its not happening here Please keep your question clear.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  //hide all the text items
  $('.list-group-item-text').hide();
  //add a click handler to the href by class
  $('.list-group-item').click(function() {
    //get the child element
    var text = $(this).find('.list-group-item-text');
    //get its state
    var state = text.is(":visible");
    //hide all the other items
    $('.list-group-item-text').hide();
    if (state == false) //show if it was hidden
      text.show();
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjqzdyj5/)

Comment: It needs to hide again when I click somewhere else. Even when I click on the list item header itself again! Thanks

Comment: @Chiel: check my answer,  it includes these

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) toggle, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfuswu6y/):

It will toggle hide and show on the selector. Check the snippet below. and to hide if clicked outside add click event on document but check condition 
`if(!$(e.target).hasClass('list-group-item-heading')`. Refer the second snippet.

```js
$("p.list-group-item-text").hide();
$(".list-group-item-heading").on("click",function(){
    $(this).next("p.list-group-item-text").toggle('slow');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading <b class="caret"></b></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum nisl ac elit commodo fringilla. Suspendisse varius nunc mauris, vitae egestas nunc cursus vitae. Ut congue odio libero, sit amet sodales arcu convallis ac. Nunc quis blandit
      metus. Aliquam hendrerit lectus vitae sapien placerat volutpat. Aenean nibh felis, volutpat sit amet maximus eget, consequat at orci. Integer pellentesque molestie elit. Donec placerat semper lacus vel blandit. Donec et dictum felis. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus consectetur diam a sagittis vestibulum. Fusce vestibulum sollicitudin venenatis.</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading <b class="caret"></b></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum nisl ac elit commodo fringilla. Suspendisse varius nunc mauris, vitae egestas nunc cursus vitae. Ut congue odio libero, sit amet sodales arcu convallis ac. Nunc quis blandit
      metus. Aliquam hendrerit lectus vitae sapien placerat volutpat. Aenean nibh felis, volutpat sit amet maximus eget, consequat at orci. Integer pellentesque molestie elit. Donec placerat semper lacus vel blandit. Donec et dictum felis. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus consectetur diam a sagittis vestibulum. Fusce vestibulum sollicitudin venenatis.</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Update [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfuswu6y/1/), to close if clicked outside

```js
$("p.list-group-item-text").hide();
$(".list-group-item-heading").on("click",function(){
    $(this).next("p.list-group-item-text").toggle('slow');
$(this).parents('.list-group-item').siblings().find("p.list-group-item-text").hide('slow');
})
$(document).on('click',function(e){
     if(!$(e.target).hasClass('list-group-item-heading') )
   {
       $("p.list-group-item-text").hide('slow');               
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading <b class="caret"></b></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum nisl ac elit commodo fringilla. Suspendisse varius nunc mauris, vitae egestas nunc cursus vitae. Ut congue odio libero, sit amet sodales arcu convallis ac. Nunc quis blandit
      metus. Aliquam hendrerit lectus vitae sapien placerat volutpat. Aenean nibh felis, volutpat sit amet maximus eget, consequat at orci. Integer pellentesque molestie elit. Donec placerat semper lacus vel blandit. Donec et dictum felis. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus consectetur diam a sagittis vestibulum. Fusce vestibulum sollicitudin venenatis.</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading <b class="caret"></b></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum nisl ac elit commodo fringilla. Suspendisse varius nunc mauris, vitae egestas nunc cursus vitae. Ut congue odio libero, sit amet sodales arcu convallis ac. Nunc quis blandit
      metus. Aliquam hendrerit lectus vitae sapien placerat volutpat. Aenean nibh felis, volutpat sit amet maximus eget, consequat at orci. Integer pellentesque molestie elit. Donec placerat semper lacus vel blandit. Donec et dictum felis. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus consectetur diam a sagittis vestibulum. Fusce vestibulum sollicitudin venenatis.</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Andrew Van Till's answer. And if you want the text to also hide when clicked again you can update his jQuery code to this;

```js
$(function() {
  $('.list-group-item-text').hide();
    $('.list-group-item').click(function(){
        if ($(this).find('.list-group-item-text').is(':visible')) {
            
            $(this).find('.list-group-item-text').hide();
        } else {
            
            $(this).find('.list-group-item-text').show();
        }        
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of repetitive content, I recommend using a templating library like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).  Build up a Javascript array with the content you want (possible returned from an Ajax query) and then use the template to fill in the list.

As for the list group item, start with an empty list-group div, and register a click() handler (using jQuery for instance) that calls your function that utilizes your template.

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tweissin/mtk0vctx/).  The javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".list-group").click(function() {
        var source   = $("#item-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        var data = [
            {heading:"List group item heading 1",text:"Lorem ipsum 1"},
            {heading:"List group item heading 2",text:"Lorem ipsum 2"}
        ];

        for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
            $(".list-group").append(template(data[i]));
        }
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="list-group">
Click to expand
</div>

<script id="item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{heading}}<b class="caret"></b></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{text}}</a>
</script>
```